# Replicate "Program" structure in C# into VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net

Why does the structure between console application seem so different between `C#` and `VB.NET`?

In `C#` I often create an instance of the Program class:

```
namespace ConsoleApplicationX {

    class Program {

        static void Main(string[] args) {

            Program p;
            p = new Program();

        ...
        ...
```

In a `VB.NET` example I have `Main` located in a file called `__ZooWork.vb` like the following:

```
Module __ZooWork

    Sub Main()

        ...
        ...
```

Can I do an equivalent implementation to the `C#` code above in `VB.NET`?

**EDIT**

I've tried the following but it errors:

[image]

**FURTHER EDIT**

Just to confirm a couple of settings - these don't seem to have solved it!...

[image]

Comment: Rename `Program` class to `Zoowork`

Comment: That error is because the startup object for the application is still set to original value. Please read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/17k74w0c(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are just the templates you can use when starting a new project. Of course you can write the equivalent code in both languages.

```
Namespace ConsoleApplicationX

    Class Program

        Shared Sub Main()

            Dim p As New Program()
            ...

        End Sub

    End Class

End Namespace
```

Comment: If I open up a new Console app and then copy your code into the file Module1.vb then it doesn't debug ....the message `'Sub Main' was not found in 'ConsoleApplication1.Module1'`

Comment: You need to [set the startup object for the application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/17k74w0c(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: I've set that to `Sub Main` but it still does not work - I will add a screenshot to OP so you can see the  complete structure

Comment: @whytheq Did you change his code from `ConsoleApplicationX` to `ConsoleApplication1`?  Also, what, if anything, is your root namespace in your project in VB set to?  My preference is to clear the root namespace so that it works more like C# does.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway mine is called `ConsoleApplication1` ...what is the safest way of changing the root namespace?

Comment: My preference is to go into the project properties and just blank it out.  And then in each code file, like C#, explicitly set the namespace.  Then you can control the namespaces.  As long as you are aware that the root namespace in VB is prepended to all namespaces in VB, you can leave it.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Thanks for clearing that up. Its been a while since I've done VB.NET, and I'd forgotten that detail.

Comment: @p.s.w.g +1 Things seem to be running now: I'm not too sure about the signature of `Main` in your solution though

Answer (score 1):

You probably shouldn't be creating an instance of the type your entry point is in to begin with.  While it's certainly *possible* in either language, it's not good design in either.

Just have your `Main` method create an instance of some other type, not the type that `Main` itself is in, and use that for your program logic.

As for the error:

> Program [...] does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

That's because your `Main` method isn't of the proper signature.  It should be:

```
Shared Sub Main()

End Sub
```

The `Shared` is important (it's the equivalent of `static` in C#; it indicates that you do not need an instance of that type to call the method, which is important for the entry point as it won't have an instance of the type before the program is started.

Comment: +1 thanks Servy. Yep - I was missing `Shared` in my implementation which was one problem. Also I was copying p.s.w.g Main signature `Main(args As String())` which was also causing a problem. In respect of creating an instance of the program from the program I have heard it is ok from some very experienced programmers and I've heard it's not good design from others .....so I guess its a matter of taste.